# putting different value numbers into array, if the input number is already in array "Retry"

Tags: java, arrays

the following code can only request to retry if the consecutive input number is the same like 1, 1 or 2, 2. But it won't request to retry if the input is like 1, 2, 1 or 2, 1, 3, 2.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class exercise {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        int[] a = new int[5];
        boolean found = false;
        int i = 1;
        System.out.println("Enter Number.\n>>>");
        a[0] = scan.nextInt();
        while(i<5)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter number.\n>>>");
            int num = scan.nextInt();
            for (int j=0; j<i; j++)  // to determine same number is already in array or not
            {
                if(a[j] == num)
                {
                    found = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
            {
                System.out.println("Retry");
            }
            else
            {
                a[i] = num;
                i++;
            }
        }
        for (int a1 : a)
            System.out.println(a1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you find the element in the array, `break` the loop. You are iterating even after you find the element in the array. Your inner loop should be like this:

```
  for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
    if(a[j] == num) {
      found = false;
      break;          // break once you find the element.
    }
    else {
      found = true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problematic part inside your code is this

```
for (int j=0; j<i; j++){            {
  if(a[j] == num){
     found = false;
   } else {
     found = true;
   }
}
```

After noticing that the number is already contained in the array, you should immediately break the for loop.

Please check also the logic in your code:

```
  if(a[j] == num){
     found = false;
   }
```

sounds strange... As you have found the element, I would have expected

```
     found = true;
```

Anyway,I suggest to move this check to a separate method. You can write a method `boolean contains(int value, int[] array)` that consists of a loop iterating over the elements of the array. If one of the elements is equal to `value`, return true.

The code could look like this:

```
boolean contains(int value, int[] array) {
  for(int j=0; j<.array.length;j++){
    if (value==array[j]){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```